# simics installation libstdc++.so.6 version not found

Tags: linker, installation, simics

I downloaded a tarball of simics from the web. 
I tried to run the `./simics-gui`
and I get this error

```
/home/leungtimothy/Desktop/simics/simics-4.0.60/amd64-linux/sys/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
```

I looked up a lot of posts, most of them are relate to linking problem. I am not able to find a libstdc++.so.6 on my 64 bits ubuntu v13.04 .

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Thank you so much

Comment: You can find more Simics related answers on the [Simics forum](http://forum.simics.net)

Answer (score 0):

`libstdc++` is the GNU Standard C++ library, which will be required by applications built with the GNU C++ compiler.

Evidently `libstdc++6` is not installed on your system. It is typically installed by installing the GNU C++ compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

If you don't need the compiler you can install `libstdc++6` independently:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: it tells me no update. Should the file in `/etc/lib/` ?

Comment: No. There should not be any such directory as `/etc/lib/`. It should be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Is it there?

Comment: Yes your right, and it is there. Then I finally solved it by making a few linking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Simics also ships with a few system libraries, that you can find in the installed base package (directory `simics-<version>`), at the path `<host>/sys/lib/`, where `libstdc++.so.6` is one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the path, it looks like it is Simics 4.0 which is over 8 years olds.

I suggest download and install the latest version of Simics from a proper source,

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/30403/Intel-Simics-Public-Release-Preview

Comment: oh.. ok, I realise now the question was asked 2014.